# How to install hdf5 on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, cmake, hdf5

HDF5 is a file format that I need to download to work with some data that I have. I am running Windows 11 on a 64 bit machine. I am finding it so difficult to install HDF5 on Windows and would be so grateful for any assistance.

Following the [HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5/) website, it seemed that I needed to build HDF5 with [cmake](https://cmake.org/). I am able to get to step 5 of the build instructions on [this webpage.](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/Building+HDF5+with+CMake)

However, when I run the following recommended command

```
  ctest -S HDF5config.cmake,BUILD_GENERATOR=VS201564 -C Release -VV -O hdf5.logsktop\CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\CMake-hdf5-1.13.2>
```

The built binary is not actually built, and I get the following error message that I do not understand

```
[OUTPUT] 
* Extra verbosity turned on

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
Reading Script: C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/HDF5config.cmake,BUILD_GENERATOR=VS201564

[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
-- Dashboard script configuration:
  CTEST_SITE=[WIN7VS201564.XXXX]
  CTEST_BUILD_NAME=[Windows-WIN10-vs2015]
  CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY=[C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2]
  CTEST_BINARY_DIRECTORY=[C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\build]
  CTEST_CMAKE_GENERATOR=[Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64]
  CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE=[Release]
  CTEST_GIT_COMMAND=[]
  CTEST_CHECKOUT_COMMAND=[]
  CTEST_CONFIGURE_COMMAND=["C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -C "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2/config/cmake/cacheinit.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release  -DHDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN:BOOL=OFF -DHDF5_BUILD_JAVA:BOOL=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=%ProgramFiles%/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.13.2 -DHDF5_ALLOW_EXTERNAL_SUPPORT:STRING=TGZ -DTGZPATH:PATH=C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2 -DHDF5_PACKAGE_EXTLIBS:BOOL=ON -DSITE:STRING=WIN7VS201564.XXXX -DBUILDNAME:STRING=Windows-WIN10-vs2015 -DCTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS:BOOL=OFF "-GVisual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "" "" "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2"]
  CTEST_SCRIPT_DIRECTORY=[C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2]
  CTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS=[0]



[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
SetCTestConfiguration:SourceDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/hdf5-1.13.2

SetCTestConfiguration:BuildDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build
[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
Run dashboard with model Experimental
   Source directory: C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2
   Build directory: C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\build

   Group: Experimental
[OUTPUT] 
   Reading ctest configuration file: C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/hdf5-1.13.2/CTestConfig.cmake

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
SetCTestConfigurationFromCMakeVariable:NightlyStartTime:CTEST_NIGHTLY_START_TIME

SetCTestConfiguration:NightlyStartTime:18:00:00 CST
SetCTestConfigurationFromCMakeVariable:Site:CTEST_SITE
SetCTestConfiguration:Site:WIN7VS201564.XXXX
SetCTestConfigurationFromCMakeVariable:BuildName:CTEST_BUILD_NAME
SetCTestConfiguration:BuildName:Windows-WIN10-vs2015
[OUTPUT] 
   Site: WIN7VS201564.XXXX
   Build name: Windows-WIN10-vs2015

   Use Experimental tag: 20220824-2256
[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
 Add coverage exclude regular expressions.

SetCTestConfiguration:BuildDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build
SetCTestConfiguration:SourceDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/hdf5-1.13.2
SetCTestConfiguration:ConfigureCommand:"C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -C "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2/config/cmake/cacheinit.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release  -DHDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN:BOOL=OFF -DHDF5_BUILD_JAVA:BOOL=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=%ProgramFiles%/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.13.2 -DHDF5_ALLOW_EXTERNAL_SUPPORT:STRING=TGZ -DTGZPATH:PATH=C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2 -DHDF5_PACKAGE_EXTLIBS:BOOL=ON -DSITE:STRING=WIN7VS201564.XXXX -DBUILDNAME:STRING=Windows-WIN10-vs2015 -DCTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS:BOOL=OFF "-GVisual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "" "" "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2"
[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
Configure project

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
Configure with command: "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -C "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2/config/cmake/cacheinit.cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release  -DHDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN:BOOL=OFF -DHDF5_BUILD_JAVA:BOOL=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=%ProgramFiles%/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.13.2 -DHDF5_ALLOW_EXTERNAL_SUPPORT:STRING=TGZ -DTGZPATH:PATH=C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2 -DHDF5_PACKAGE_EXTLIBS:BOOL=ON -DSITE:STRING=WIN7VS201564.XXXX -DBUILDNAME:STRING=Windows-WIN10-vs2015 -DCTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS:BOOL=OFF "-GVisual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "" "" "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2"

Run command: "C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" "-C" "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2/config/cmake/cacheinit.cmake" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release" "-DHDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN:BOOL=OFF" "-DHDF5_BUILD_JAVA:BOOL=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=%ProgramFiles%/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.13.2" "-DHDF5_ALLOW_EXTERNAL_SUPPORT:STRING=TGZ" "-DTGZPATH:PATH=C:/Users/User" "Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2" "-DHDF5_PACKAGE_EXTLIBS:BOOL=ON" "-DSITE:STRING=WIN7VS201564.XXXX" "-DBUILDNAME:STRING=Windows-WIN10-vs2015" "-DCTEST_USE_LAUNCHERS:BOOL=OFF" "-GVisual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "" "" "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2"
CMake Warning:
  Ignoring empty string ("") provided on the command line.


CMake Warning:
  Ignoring empty string ("") provided on the command line.


CMake Warning:
  Ignoring extra path from command line:

   "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build/Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2"

loading initial cache file C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2\hdf5-1.13.2/config/cmake/cacheinit.cmake

-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.22000.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Looking for include file sys/file.h
-- Looking for include file sys/file.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for include file sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/resource.h
-- Looking for include file sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/socket.h
-- Looking for include file sys/socket.h - not found
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h
-- Looking for include file sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include files sys/stat.h, sys/time.h
-- Looking for include files sys/stat.h, sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for include files sys/stat.h, sys/types.h
-- Looking for include files sys/stat.h, sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., features.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., features.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., dirent.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., dirent.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., unistd.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pwd.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pwd.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., globus/common.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., globus/common.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pdb.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pdb.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pthread.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., pthread.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., srbclient.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., srbclient.h - not found
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., string.h
-- Looking for 3 include files sys/stat.h, ..., string.h - found
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/stat.h, ..., strings.h
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/stat.h, ..., strings.h - not found
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/stat.h, ..., stdlib.h
-- Looking for 4 include files sys/stat.h, ..., stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for 5 include files sys/stat.h, ..., memory.h
-- Looking for 5 include files sys/stat.h, ..., memory.h - found
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., dlfcn.h
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., netinet/in.h
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., netinet/in.h - not found
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., netdb.h
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., netdb.h - not found
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., arpa/inet.h
-- Looking for 6 include files sys/stat.h, ..., arpa/inet.h - not found
-- Looking for include file quadmath.h
-- Looking for include file quadmath.h - not found
-- Looking for gethostname in ucb;
-- Looking for gethostname in ucb; - not found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of char
-- Check size of char - done
-- Check size of short
-- Check size of short - done
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of unsigned
-- Check size of unsigned - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of float
-- Check size of float - done
-- Check size of double
-- Check size of double - done
-- Check size of long double
-- Check size of long double - done
-- Check size of int8_t
-- Check size of int8_t - done
-- Check size of uint8_t
-- Check size of uint8_t - done
-- Check size of int_least8_t
-- Check size of int_least8_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least8_t
-- Check size of uint_least8_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast8_t
-- Check size of int_fast8_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast8_t
-- Check size of uint_fast8_t - done
-- Check size of int16_t
-- Check size of int16_t - done
-- Check size of uint16_t
-- Check size of uint16_t - done
-- Check size of int_least16_t
-- Check size of int_least16_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least16_t
-- Check size of uint_least16_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast16_t
-- Check size of int_fast16_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast16_t
-- Check size of uint_fast16_t - done
-- Check size of int32_t
-- Check size of int32_t - done
-- Check size of uint32_t
-- Check size of uint32_t - done
-- Check size of int_least32_t
-- Check size of int_least32_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least32_t
-- Check size of uint_least32_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast32_t
-- Check size of int_fast32_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast32_t
-- Check size of uint_fast32_t - done
-- Check size of int64_t
-- Check size of int64_t - done
-- Check size of uint64_t
-- Check size of uint64_t - done
-- Check size of int_least64_t
-- Check size of int_least64_t - done
-- Check size of uint_least64_t
-- Check size of uint_least64_t - done
-- Check size of int_fast64_t
-- Check size of int_fast64_t - done
-- Check size of uint_fast64_t
-- Check size of uint_fast64_t - done
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - failed
-- Check size of off_t
-- Check size of off_t - done
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Check size of time_t
-- Check size of time_t - done
-- Check size of _Bool
-- Check size of _Bool - done
-- Looking for alarm
-- Looking for alarm - not found
-- Looking for fcntl
-- Looking for fcntl - not found
-- Looking for flock
-- Looking for flock - not found
-- Looking for fork
-- Looking for fork - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for lstat
-- Looking for lstat - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for pwrite
-- Looking for pwrite - not found
-- Looking for rand_r
-- Looking for rand_r - not found
-- Looking for random
-- Looking for random - not found
-- Looking for setsysinfo
-- Looking for setsysinfo - not found
-- Looking for siglongjmp
-- Looking for siglongjmp - not found
-- Looking for sigsetjmp
-- Looking for sigsetjmp - not found
-- Looking for sigprocmask
-- Looking for sigprocmask - not found
-- Looking for srandom
-- Looking for srandom - not found
-- Looking for symlink
-- Looking for symlink - not found
-- Looking for tmpfile
-- Looking for tmpfile - found
-- Looking for asprintf
-- Looking for asprintf - not found
-- Looking for vasprintf
-- Looking for vasprintf - not found
-- Looking for waitpid
-- Looking for waitpid - not found
-- Looking for sigsetjmp
-- Looking for sigsetjmp - not found
-- Check size of __float128
-- Check size of __float128 - failed
-- Check size of _Quad
-- Check size of _Quad - failed
-- Testing maximum decimal precision for C - Exit code 0xc0000135

CMake Error at config/cmake/ConfigureChecks.cmake:318 (list):
  list index: 1 out of range (-1, 0)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:469 (include)

-- maximum decimal precision for C var - 0

-- Found Perl: C:/cygwin64/bin/perl.exe (found version "5.26.3") 
-- ....All Warnings are enabled
-- Filter PLUGIN file C:/Users/User/hdf5_plugins.tar.gz not found
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- ....All Warnings are enabled
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Command exited with the value: 1
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
Error(s) when configuring the project

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
SetCTestConfiguration:BuildDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build

SetCTestConfiguration:SourceDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/hdf5-1.13.2
SetMakeCommand:"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --config "Release"
SetCTestConfiguration:MakeCommand:"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --config "Release"
SetCTestConfiguration:UseLaunchers:0
[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
Build project

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
MakeCommand:"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --config "Release"

Run command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" "--build" "." "--config" "Release"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
Command exited with the value: 1
MakeCommand:"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build . --config "Release"
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
Error(s) when building project

[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
   1 Compiler errors

   1 Compiler warnings
[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
SetCTestConfiguration:BuildDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build

SetCTestConfiguration:SourceDirectory:C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/hdf5-1.13.2
[HANDLER_OUTPUT] 
Test project C:/Users/User Name/Desktop/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/CMake-hdf5-1.13.2/build

[HANDLER_VERBOSE_OUTPUT] 
Constructing a list of tests

Updating test list for fixtures
Added 0 tests to meet fixture requirements
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
[ERROR_MESSAGE] 
No tests were found!!!
```

Really any pointers or references to things I could read to better understand what is going on would be appreciated, because I really do not understand this error message.

However, I am a bit worried that a possible bug could be coming from that fact that my User for this laptop is User Name, i.e. it has a space in it.

The HDF5 site has a warning that Blank spaces MUST NOT be used in directory path names as this will cause the build to fail.

However, [this site](https://www.minitool.com/news/change-user-folder-name-windows-10.html) warns that changing a User Folder name can be super risky, and I'd really not do that if at all possible.

Comment: "The HDF5 site has a warning that Blank spaces MUST NOT be used in directory path names as this will cause the build to fail." - This doesn't mean that you should change the  name of the User Folder. You could build HDF5 outside of your home directory at all.

Comment: Have you considered using the pre-built binaries on The HDF Group website? It's pretty simple to install - and no need for `make`.